# Mailer returning EOFError from server but not from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, smtp, ruby-on-rails-5

I set up a mailer for my rails app. I swear it was working just a few days ago, but now I'm suddenly getting an EOFError when I try to send an email. I can send emails from my rails console, but I get the following minimalist error whenever I try it from my rails server:

> EOFError: end of file reached

If there were a problem with my configuration or some connectivity problem, I don't think it would work from console either, so I'm pretty confused. What could be the problem?

It's worth noting that I used to get a "suspicious sign-in attempt blocked" message from the email address I'm using, but I no longer even get that message, only the EOFError. This is true for both development and production.

I also tried changing my port to 465, but nothing changed.

**Development.rb:**

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    domain: 'gmail.com',
    user_name: 'address@gmail.com',
    password: 'Password',
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

**Production.rb:**

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://website.com' }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    domain: 'gmail.com',
    user_name: 'address@gmail.com',
    password: 'Password',
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

**mailers/order_mailer.rb**

```
class OrderMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'address@gmail.com'

  def contact(body)
    @body = body
    mail(to: "otheraddress@gmail.com", subject: "New")
  end
end
```

**To test, I enter the following into, respectively, my rails console and my binding.pry server console. The former sends an email successfuly, the latter gives an EOFError.**

```
OrderMailer.contact("body").deliver
```

Comment: Does it affect things if you change authentication type from 'plain' to 'login' in development?

Comment: Is it looking-for (and failing to find) a mailer-view or layout or some other file?

Comment: @rantingsonrails I changed 'plain' to 'login' and now it works on development, but not on production.

Comment: @JoeMorano Are both dev and prod using port 587 now?

Comment: @JoeMorano Also another guess for production to try `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'website.com', protocol:'http' }`

Comment: @rantingsonrails Yes, both are using port 587. I tried your latest code, but the email still isn't being sent.

Comment: @rantingsonrails For the love of god, now I'm getting the EOFError on development again, but I didn't even change the code.

Comment: @JoeMorano First of all Google is a pain sometimes, so take heart. The EOF error is a message that Google is sending saying that they are denying access. Do you have a google apps account that you're using here, ie your own domain, or just trying to send through your me@gmail.com account?

Comment: @JoeMorano Also, in development, if you use a gem like mailcatcher, do you see the email being sent?

Comment: @JoeMorano Also, as a shot in the dark, you can try removing `default from: 'address@gmail.com'` and specify from in the `mail(..., from:"address@gmail.com")`

Comment: @rantingsonrails That's the weird thing, Google sent me an email the first few times that it blocked a suspicious sign-in attempt, but I've tried about 50 times since then and I never get a warning anymore. I'm using a x@gmail.com account with less secure apps enabled, so I don't know what else I can do. I'm not using mailcatcher. The content of the email is printed in my terminal, but then I get a 500 EOF error.

Comment: @rantingsonrails I changed that, and now it works on development again, but still not on production.

Comment: @JoeMorano Production rails console is sending the email without issue? The problem is just when running the command through the local web server?

Comment: @JoeMorano Also, with the above changes regarding the `default_url_options`, can you add `tls:true` using port 465 on production?

`config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  tls: true,
  address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 465,
  ...  }`

Comment: @rantingsonrails No, it runs without issue on my local server, but I just checked my production server, and I'm actually getting a "Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted" error, but my username and password are both definitely correct. I also tried to create another gmail and yahoo account, but those did the same thing.

Comment: @rantingsonrails I tried that, but I'm still getting the same error. This is ridiculous. I'm going to try the 'gmail' gem.

Comment: Completely anecdotal: I've gotten this error because of a bizarrely-setup HTTP proxy server before.

Comment: @JoshBrody Thank you so much for helping me this far. This is one of the most ridiculous bugs I've ever encountered. I found a gem called 'gmail' that works perfectly, so I'm totally abandoning ActionMailer. It's way too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html), you should be passing a mail body via param, not manipulating `@body` eg:

```
  def contact(body)
    mail(to: "otheraddress@gmail.com", subject: "New", body: body)
  end
```

Note: not sure if this will solve it, but worth a try?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I even came close to solving this bug. Instead, I switched to using the 'gmail' gem, which I would recommend for everyone trying to build an email function. ActionMailer is way too fragile and unstable for my taste.

This is all the code I need:

```
require 'gmail'
gmail = Gmail.connect('youremail@ex.com', 'password')
email = gmail.compose do
  to "theiremail@ex.com"
  subject "New Message"
  body "Body"
end
gmail.deliver(email)
```